# Python mechanize module: Default documentation is not complete

Tags: python, html, forms, mechanize-python

I am using Python Mechanize module to traverse through forms and see the controls, contents etc. [This](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/doc.html) documentation is incomplete and hence can anybody share details of all the methods?

Also, I am not able to make out the difference between submit() and click() methods on forms. Please comment on that too.